# Implement Bootstrap CSS to use properly ng-bootstrap into Angular 4 CLI project

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Hi Stackoverflow community !

Just a simple question to be sure, I am implementing Ng-Bootstrap in my Angular 4 project using the following link
[Getting started ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and I've got a doubt about lines number 2 they says: " The only required dependencies are: **Bootstrap CSS** ", but what does it mean exactly? Because when you click on the hyperlink on the same sentence it brings you there [Download bootstrap link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) there's plenty files (bootstrap.grid.css, boostrap.reboot.css, etc..). So according to theses files my question is: should I had all theses files and their links to my projects assets and into my angular-cli.json "styles" and "scripts" or just bootstrap.min.css should be enough?

**Note** that I actually need just the "datepicker" element. (maybe more later in the project..)

Thanks in advance for your opinions and answeres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you need to include the bootstrap styles. Update your `.angular-cli.json` file to include the bootstrap styles for your app:

```
"styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css",
  ],
```

Comment: sounds good so I'll just need that, no jquery no bootstrap.js?

Comment: if you have followed the tutorial that you mentioned and as you say your are using anuglar-cli, then that's all you need.

Comment: you'll also need to install `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` from npm using `$ npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`

Comment: this morning I start my ng serve --open and I've got this message in the terminlal : `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/papamilo/Documents/Workspace/Test_a2json/front-end_copy_new/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/home/papamilo/Documents/Workspace/Test_a2json/front-end_copy_new/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'` Should I open a new post for that do you think?

Comment: here is the link to my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633001/error-during-install-ng-bootsrap-on-my-angular-4-cli-project